# Creating data extension template

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

How can we create a data extension template? I know we can create data extensions from a template but how to create the template itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get these created by creating a support ticket. It doesn't need an actual services engagement, but raise a ticket detailing the name, fields and dataypes and have it provisioned through Manage by the Support Team. Make sure you stipulate the MIDs you need it provisioned to.

Comment: This is no longer an option anymore (2022/05) per support.

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer an option to create a data extension template, you will need to copy existing DE or use another method to create these, such as ssjs or API calls